# Can't open a link when the default browser has been changed

Tags: swift, url, uikit, ios14

After updating to iOS 14 I cannot open urls in the browser if it has been changed from default Safari to Chrome.

I did some investigation and found that `UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url)` always returns false.

Please help.

Comment: https://medium.com/@guanshanliu/lsapplicationqueriesschemes-4f5fa9c7d240

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For iOS 14+**

I suggest to add this to your Info.plist

```
 <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
      <string>https</string>
    </array>
```

By adding this you can continue to use method `canOpenURL(_ url: URL) -> Bool`

```
guard let url = URL(string: "https://example.com") else { return }
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
}
```